# Instantiate ViewController when using Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am using `Storyboard` and want to push a view controller for display in `UITabBarController` at the click of tab bar item.

For this, I am using an existing `ViewController` linked to `TabBarController` created on `Storyboard` and using below code. However, I get exception, *Storyboard doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'SwitchViewController'*

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

        let switchViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SwitchViewController")
        self.presentViewController(switchViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return false
    }
```

**UPDATE**: I added `Storyboard ID` for `SwitchViewController` in `Main.storyboard` and commented the above code. App Failed with same error when I moved to this tab

I am using iOS 8 and Xcode 7. Kindly help

Comment: I was using correct code, but my first `ViewController` was missing the `rootViewController` relationship from `NavigationController` that caused this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your Storyboard ID,

[image]

Try this one,

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

    if viewController is SwitchViewController {
        let switchViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SwitchViewController") as! SwitchViewController
        self.presentViewController(switchViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: I guess you meant to write `viewController is SwitchViewController`. Anyway, even this code fails. Still same error. Problem is no matter what I do, it always complain, "Unable to find Identifier in the view". **I have a UITabBarController and SwitchViewController is attached to tab bar**

Comment: Could you please list out your steps? Because, for me it fails even if I just add Storyboard ID in the storyboard. What is your version of Xcode?

Comment: I tried with a new project and it worked too. But, then what is wrong with my existing project? Before I started the app, I had deleted the default view controller provided by Xcode and instead, used new view controller. Could that be the problem?

Comment: That's good to hear. May be, yes. I don't know exactly. I think it is better not to spend your time to trivial and not important things.

Comment: It worked. Mistakenly, I had deleted Main.storyboard a week before and after restoring it, I guess the rootViewController info was lost. I did notice some screens breaking, but thought I might lost some connections. 'After re-initiating the rootViewController connection, it finally worked.`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let VC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SwitchViewController")

Comment: Tried. Doesn't work. I get the storyboard object, but inside it, it's not able to find the `ViewController`